# Swift Storyboard appearance changes don't get updated when run

Tags: swift, xcode, appearance

I've made some changes on the button appearance on the Storyboard but when I run it on the simulator or physical device, the changes don't get updated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57xB0.jpg)

Any solutions?

EDIT: Added storyboard screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W491G.png)

Comment: is it iOS 14? and are you setting a .png as background?

Comment: ios 13. no just color for background

Comment: Can you show the storyboard information via a screenshot please?

Comment: Uploaded storyboard screenshot

Comment: I think it might have to be a problem with the specifications of foreground and background being "default"

Comment: Try changing those values of the button to the specific color you want and see what happens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have made changes in the storyboard that involve new iOS 15 button features. Those features don't exist in iOS 13 so naturally you don't see them there.